# Why content span:after {content: ' '} is put inside span and not after?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Why this CSS ...

```
.sticky-info span:after {content: 'test';}
```

... results in ...

```
<div class="sticky-info"><span>Price <strong>&euro;120</strong>::after</span>
```

Is there a way to get the `content:'test'` behind every `</span>` inside `<div class="sticky-info">` There are several spans inside `<div class="sticky-info">`

Comment: so u want to replace the ::after with test????

Comment: No, that's not possible using CSS generated content, unless you move the `::after` pseudo-element to the parent `<div>`.

Comment: `::before` and `::after` means **before/after the CONTENT** of the element.

Comment: `::before` and `::after` is shadow DOM of the element it is applied to. You can’t add them at the same level. You’ll have to come up with something else my friend.

Comment: What do you mean by "behind the span"?

Comment: I want to put the content behind every </span> inside .sticky-info
Something like this

<div class="sticky-info"><span>Price <strong>&euro;120</strong></span> test<span>Price <strong>&euro;120</strong></span> test<span>Price <strong>&euro;120</strong></span> test</div>

Comment: possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473976/why-is-the-pseudo-content-after-not-shown-after-but-in-the-corresponding-div/28474453#28474453

Comment: You need to do `::after` on the `.sticky-info`. __AFTER__ the content of the element. You can't modify things _outside_ of the selected element.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
<div class="sticky-info">
    <span>Price <strong>&euro;120</strong></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky-info:after {content: 'test';}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. It will add content behind the span.

Comment: I imagine it was downvoted because what the OP wants is a solution that adds content after EACH span tag. With your solution it will only add content to the end of the div tag. To achieve what the OP really wants he would have to add a <div> tag container around every <span> (I upvoted you though because you're not wrong).

Comment: Thanks, seems OP added that requirement after I posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

`::before` and `::after` means before/after the CONTENT of the element so it's not possible in this way.
Thx @Paulie_D and @Tim S.

Comment: Can you please expand this answer a little more and explain what you did end up doing to solve it?

Comment: Sure it is possible, see the other answers.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: basically I wanted a break after every <span> inside a certain <div>, on small viewport. On a large viewport there was no need for a break. Instead of trying to add a break on a small viewport I worked the other way around an hided the breaks on a large screen.

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9g8qzt3f/

If you use span::after the after will be added to the span, behind its content.
To get it behind the span, use

```
 .sticky-info:after {content: 'test';}
```

Comment: That's the problem, I have several spans inside .sticky info

Comment: Basicly I want to put a break after every span inside .sticky-info

'code'.sticky-info span:after {
content: '';
display: block;
}

Comment: @MDC if you want to put a break.. use padding or margin.

Comment: @MDC you should mention things like that in your question, else noone will know about it. My method only works if you have one span, since your question only mentioned one. If you want to use it for multiple, your best call would be to use jquery for that.