# What does content: "#702f8a -> #560079 @ 90° do in CSS

Tags: css

I really tried google a lot but couldn't figure out what does this css do.

Could you help please.

```
.XXX-purple-gradient:after {
    content: "#702f8a -> #560079 @ 90┬░"
}
```

Also when compass compile the Sass, it converts 90° to 90┬░. Is this going to cause any issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I think I was not clear what I was asking. I understand what does the CSS attribute content do, but just don't understand why they do this, because obviously they are displaying CSS styling on the actual page.

Comment: Umm, thank you but to me, that didn't answer my question, because it doesn't explain why people do that, what's the business purpose of it. I thank you for your detailed answers on the technical part, but as for the actual question, it didn't address my puzzle. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suddenly understood what was this for. They are for demo purposes, every class has a style assigned, and this part of attributes explain what it is. By doing this way, they can use css to add the descriptions.

Problem resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Whether you use the [`"deg"`](http://www.bootply.com/pv1Mv2cnNG) version or the [`"°"`](http://www.bootply.com/ppXmsfbtb9), the result is the same.

The `Css` selector is a class selector, that applies the `content` provided in the double quotes `after` the element. It basically appends `"#702f8a -> #560079 @ 90°"`. I suggest looking into the pseudo-selectors described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980475/after-vs-after).

Here is how it renders:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
.container:after {
  content: "#702f8a -> #560079 @ 90°"
}
.well {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.well:after {
  content: "#702f8a -> #560079 @ 90deg"
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="well">
    <h1> World</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the word `deg` instead of °

```
.XXX-purple-gradient:after {
    content: "#702f8a -> #560079 @ 90deg
}
```